# AVL tree partition

Tags: algorithms, trees, recursive-algorithms

The statement sais the following

> Design a function to partition an AVL tree such that, given an AVL tree and a key $x$, it returns two AVL trees, one containing the keys lower or equal than $x$, and the other containing the remaining keys. The complexity must be better than $\mathcal{O}(n)$ (being $n$ the cardinality of the tree).

My attempt is the following recursive algorithm (in pseudo code, so notation abuse is probable).

`split(T x, Node root, Node link, Node lower){
    if(root.key <= x){
        if(lower.isEmpty())
            lower=BinaryTree(root.left,root,null);
        else link.right = BinaryTree(root.left,root,null);
        link = root;
        if (root.key< x)
            split(x,root.right.root,link,lower);
    } else split(x,root.left.root,link,lower);
}`

if I am not mistaken, the algorithm returns a binary search tree (but possibly not balanced) whose keys are the ones in the original tree lower of equal than $x$. An analogous one can be done to build the other tree.

So, the question is how to balance both trees without icreasing the current $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy was wrong. Its better to distinguish cases depending on $x>\text{root}$ or $x\leq \text{root}$. Building the "higher tree" in the first case and the "lower tree" otherwise. For details about balancing take a look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80436/avl-tree-partition) (same question in a more specific stack exchange forum).

Answer (score -1):

An alternate but easy solution is to search for key x and create two sorted lists $S$ and $L$ where $S$ contains all elements les than $x$ and vice-versa for $L$, which can be done in linear time.

Now create a perfect binary search tree on this.
If the elements are already sorted, this can be done in linear time.
Every perfect binary search tree is a valid AVL tree.
Viola :D

Comment: As you say, creating the sorted lists will take linear time, and we want to make an algorithm which is strictly faster.

Comment: It is in linear time. How do expect it to be faster than that?

Comment: As you can see here, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80436/avl-tree-partition it can be done in $\mathcal{O}(\log^2)$